Nginx error in error.log - 111: Connection refused
Server on nodejs (run via pm2). Everything works fine, users don’t complain, but for some reason the following errors appear in nginx’s error.log on average every 5-10 seconds:
2024/10/05 16:55:56 [error] 247972#247972: *42617938 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.68.&&&.&&&, server: &&&&&.net, request: "POST /api/banners HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/banners", host: "&&&&&.net", referrer: "https://&&&&&.net/mining/mining"

I'm at a loss. I don't know what this might be connected with. Everything works perfectly for me, and for users too. I have no idea why these errors appear.
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name &&&&&.net www.&&&&&.net;

    return 302 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;

    server_name &&&&&.net www.&&&&&.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}

Sounds dumb, but I thought I could catch this error from me by reloading the page many times. In the end I didn't have any errors.
I’m ready to provide all the necessary information, just help please =)

Is the referrer accessible, and is the upstream accessible, generally, on that localhost? If it serves other URLs, why may that deny it? Does that service log errors or warnings or infos aboutthe rejection?
